# How to skip blanks with arrayformula(min(countif())) function?

Tags: google-sheets

My Formula is the following

```
=arrayformula(MIN(countif(F9:F,F9:F)))
```

but it does not skip blank cells. How do I get it to skip blank cells?

Answer (score 0):

Filter the counted cells first.

```
=arrayformula(min(countif(filter(F9:F, not(isblank(f9:f))),F9:F)))
```

Speaking of which, min(countif()) seems redundant, countif should give you a single number so min() does not change anything.